# Is there a way to have SQL give results with 2 layers? RESULT1 | RESULT1-Items

Tags: sql

I was trying to find a way to format the results as if there was a "FOR EACH" loop, like

```
   for each (teacher in result) select student 
   if student.teachernumber = teacher.teachernumber
```

So the results would show

```
   TeacherName
        Student1
        Student2
        etc.
```

But I cant seem to find a way to get that output - I want each student query seperated by their teacher info so I can parse it into a script

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for a join:

```
SELECT t.Name AS TeacherName,
       t.TeacherNumber,
       s.Name AS Student
FROM dbo.Teacher t
INNER JOIN dbo.Student s
    ON t.TeacherNumber = s.TeacherNumber
```

If you also want (and it's possible) that a student has no teacher, use `OUTER JOIN`.